# How to fetch all post and post comments posted by any user and his friends

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am working on an asp.net application "social networking site".in this i am working on the following tables:-

```
Friends(ID,User_ID,Friend_ID)
Users(User_ID,User_Name,Full_Name,DOB,Gender)
User_Detail(ID,User_ID,Image,Father_Name,Mother_Name,Location,JobProfile)
Wall(Wall_ID,Wall_Content,TimeAgo,User_ID)
Wall_Comments(Comment_ID,Wall_ID,Comments,Comment_Date,User_ID)
```

I want to select all records of Tables- Wall and Wall_Comments where User_ID=5 and all friends of User_ID=5
I have done following Sql Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (30) wall.wall_content, 
                         wall.wall_id, 
                         wall.user_id, 
                         wall.timeago, 
                         users.user_name, 
                         users.full_name, 
                         users.user_id                                 AS UID, 
                         wall_comments.comments, 
                         wall_comments.comment_id, 
                         CONVERT(NVARCHAR(1000), user_detail.image, 0) AS Image 
FROM   friends 
       INNER JOIN users 
               ON friends.user_id = users.user_id 
       INNER JOIN wall 
               ON users.user_id = wall.user_id 
       INNER JOIN user_detail 
               ON users.user_id = user_detail.user_id 
       left outer join wall_comments 
               ON wall.wall_id = wall_comments.wall_id 
WHERE  ( users.user_id IN (SELECT friend_id 
                           FROM   friends AS Friends_1 
                           WHERE  ( user_id = 5 )) ) 
UNION 
SELECT wall.wall_content, 
       wall.wall_id, 
       wall.user_id, 
       wall.timeago, 
       users.user_name, 
       users.full_name, 
       users.user_id                                 AS UID, 
       wall_comments.comments, 
       wall_comments.comment_id, 
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(1000), user_detail.image, 0) AS Image 
FROM   wall 
       INNER JOIN users 
               ON wall.user_id = users.user_id 
       INNER JOIN user_detail 
               ON users. user_id = user_detail.user_id 
       left outer join wall_comments 
               ON wall.wall_id = wall_comments.wall_id 
WHERE  ( users.user_id = 5 ) 
ORDER  BY wall.wall_id DESC
```

But it is showing only one record of table wall and Wall_Comments of user_ID-5 it is not showing his friends Wall and their post.and If their is not any comment on any wall then it is not showing.please Help me someone.

Comment: I did it by adding left outer JOIN wall_comments 
               ON wall.wall_id = wall_comments.wall_id in place of Inner join.It is working.But each Wall_Comment record is showing in different.I want all Wall_Comments of specific Wall_ID in single row

Comment: I did it By own.Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select *
from Friends
inner join Wall_Comments On (Wall_Comments.User_ID = Friends.User_ID or Wall_Comments.User_ID = Friends.Friend_ID)
inner join Users On Users.User_ID = Wall_Comments.User_ID
where Friends.User_ID = 5
```